# Powershell Script that moves files based on filename

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, filenames, move

I am working on a Script that moves files from an USB Device to my Desktop. The Files should go in a seperade order based on the filename:

Files:

```
xx_xx_122.xx
xx_xx_143.xx
xx_xx_129.xx
```

Folder:

```
xx_122
xx_143
xx_129
```

Currently stuck here:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Schule"


$targetFolder = "C:\Privat"

foreach($file in $fileList)
{

    If($file.Name -match "122"){

        $folderName = $matches[0]


        if(!(Test-Path "C:\Schule\$folderName")){New-Item "C:\Privat\$folderName" -type directory} 

        Move-Item "C:\Schule\$file" "C:\Privat\$folderName"                  
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to change your approach first. You first go through the list of items in USB and just focus on creation of folders with the names that you pick. It might be 1000 different names like 122,143,129, so on and so fort. 
Then use a final foreach loop where you use move item if matches the file names with the folder names using wildcard. That way, it will sort out all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex.

I think something like this is what you want:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Temp\powershell\files"
$targetFolder = "C:\Temp\powershell\folder"

$files = Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder

foreach($file in $files){
    if($file.name -match "(_)(?!.*\1)(.*)\."){
        $newFolderName = $matches[2]
        $newFolderPath = "$targetFolder\$newFolderName"
        if(!(Test-Path $newFolderPath)){
            New-Item $newFolderPath -type directory
        }
        Move-Item "$sourceFolder\$file" $newFolderPath
    }
}
```

## Input:

```
C:\Temp\powershell\files
|-def_122.txt
|-abc_132.txt
```

## Output:

```
C:\Temp\powershell\folder
|-122
  |-def_122.txt
|-132
  |-abc_132.txt
```